# Write custom properties in word document when Word is not running

Tags: ms-word, vsto

My .NET application (a file manager capable of tagging documents) must be able to read and write Custom Properties in a Word document.

The application must be able to do this both when the document is open in Word and when Word is not running.

(And it must do the same for Excel and Powerpoint documents, not only Word documents.)

My question is how to solve this problem.

Update: Here is how I think it can be solved:

1) To handle the case where the document is not open in Word: the app will write the custom properties directly to the document file, via [the openXml api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh674468.aspx). But what if the document is .doc and not .docx? What Api shall I use?

2) to handle the case where the document is open in Word: I will create a Word add-in, and then the application will send a message to the add-in (via a named pipe), telling "add this custom property to the document". The add-in would then add the property as is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx).

Do you think there are problems with the above architecture?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: "the app will write the custom properties directly to the document file, via the openXml api." - Will this app be running on machines that doesnt have Microsoft Office or only when Microsoft Office is available in the machines.

Comment: the app must run on machines that don't have office.

Comment: You could have a single project using Open XML and it can be called from your App and WordAddin. Once the custom properties been set it makes the document dirty and it has to be saved. I think saving the document should be done from its calling point whether it is your app or Addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to question (1), which I found in the meantime:

To read and write custom properties in old .doc files (office 2003), I used [dsofile.dll](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8422).

then

regsvr32 DSOFile.dll

then, in your visual studio project, add a reference to dsofile.dll.

then write the code.

A difficulty was that the library is only for 32 bit. For 64 bit, the difference is: I had to find a 64-bit compiled version ([link](http://www.keysolutions.com/blogs/kenyee.nsf/d6plinks/KKYE-79KRU6)). Then again I had to

regsvr32 DSOFile.dll

Then I added to my vstudio project a reference *not* to that dll, but to Interop.DSOFile.dll.